# Edit 1st page only

Tags: packages

There is a doc created by someone else, that I need to style.

I am using Sphinx-doc, and below is the overriden latex premable. I want to customize the title page.

```
latex_preamble = r'''
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage[postscript]{ucs}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{xcolor}

% Nimbus Samns L - helvetica clone
\setmainfont{Nimbus Sans L}

% Header and footer
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\definecolor{headercolor}{HTML}{8CC7EC}
\renewcommand{\headrule}{\color{headercolor}\hrule height 0.8pt}
\rhead{Technical Guide}
\lhead{\leftmark}
\lfoot{\copyright\xspace 2017. All rights reserved.}
\rfoot{\thepage}

% Table of Contents
% ToC: depth
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
...
'''

latex_elements = {
    'sphinxsetup': '',
    'passoptionstopackages': r'\PassOptionsToPackage{table}{xcolor}',
    'preamble': latex_preamble,
}
```

My goals:

[image]

Comment: To remove header line: `\renewcommand{\headrule}{}`.

Comment: Your code does not contain code for the other parts you asked.

Comment: `\renewcommand{\headrule}{}` didn't work. Recompiled the file - the line is steal there. Is it supposed to be put at some particular place?

Comment: Strange. So change `0.8pt` to `0pt`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Please read the [introductory material](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) for this site. When you post a question, please provide a ["Minimal Working Example" (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that starts with `\documentclass`, includes all relevant `\usepackage` commands, ends with `\end{document}` and compiles without errors, even if it does not produce your desired output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sphinx-doc allows you to override certain latex elements easily. For example in this case you want to customize the title page. To do that you need to override the `\maketitle` macro:

```
latex_maketitle = r'''
\begin{titlepage}
\noindent \Huge Example title \par
\sphinxlogo
\end{titlepage}
'''

# allow utf8 characters
latex_elements = {
    'sphinxsetup': '',
    'passoptionstopackages': r'\PassOptionsToPackage{table}{xcolor}',
    'preamble': latex_preamble,
    'maketitle': latex_maketitle,
}
```

In this example the result will be your title + the default logo image you have used.

The original Sphinx `\maketitle` macro can be found here:

https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/blob/c892fe98f7a311dc51340f8d98e63d9790b7f820/sphinx/texinputs/sphinxhowto.cls#L30-L58

```
% Change the title page to look a bit better, and fit in with the fncychap
% ``Bjarne'' style a bit better.
%
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{%
  \noindent\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}\par
    \begingroup % for PDF information dictionary
       \def\endgraf{ }\def\and{\& }%
       \pdfstringdefDisableCommands{\def\\{, }}% overwrite hyperref setup
       \hypersetup{pdfauthor={\@author}, pdftitle={\@title}}%
    \endgroup
  \begin{flushright}
    \sphinxlogo
    \py@HeaderFamily
    {\Huge \@title }\par
    {\itshape\large \py@release \releaseinfo}\par
    \vspace{25pt}
    {\Large
      \begin{tabular}[t]{c}
        \@author
      \end{tabular}}\par
    \vspace{25pt}
    \@date \par
    \py@authoraddress \par
  \end{flushright}
  \@thanks
  \setcounter{footnote}{0}
  \let\thanks\relax\let\maketitle\relax
  %\gdef\@thanks{}\gdef\@author{}\gdef\@title{}
}
```

You can base your changes on this to get what you want.